# Algebraic Shifting Computer Code

Tags: computer-algebra, algebraic-combinatorics, simplicial-complexes

Is anyone aware of computer code that will algebraically shift a simplicial complex (as in this [Kalai paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.26.2796))? Ideally, I am looking for an implementation that can run in something like Sage or Macaulay2.

Answer (score 1):

Lorenzo Venturello has implemented a method to compute the algebraic shifting of a simplicial complex in Macaulay2. The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Macaulay2/M2/pull/831/commits/2a3806d7766c6ecc86d579914245124f8bc4c024), it is not yet "official", but you might want to try it out.